# Can I use git push origin master:myBranch to push code I modified in master branch to my branch?

Tags: git, github

Can I use `git push origin master:myBranch` to push code I modified in master branch to my branch? Will this affect the master branch?

Comment: In this command, `master` refers to the `master` branch in the local repository, and `myBranch` refers to the `myBranch` in the remote repository. It's going to update `myBranch` in the remote repository. The `master` branch in the local repository and the one in the remote repository won't get changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, and that won't affect your local or remote `master` branch.

But it is better to create `myBranch` locally (from your current `master`) and push it to its remote tracking equivalent:

```
git switch -c myBranch
git push -u origin myBranch
```

Next time you are committing on `myBranch`, a simple `git push` will be enough to push the local  `myBranch` to the remote `myBranch`.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is checkout to myBranch and do a "git merge master", which merge the up to date master to my branch, and then do git commit and git push to push the code